# Select not posting information MVC Identity

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have created a registration page for my MVC web application. When I try to register a user the information from the cuisine_1, cuisine_2 and cuisine_3 select boxes is not entered into the UserCuisineInfo table. However a new row is created with an id and an error message is displayed on the web page saying that cuisine_1, cuisine_2 and cuisine_3 fields are required.

Register web page

```
@model Bitev2.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new SelectList(new[] {"Female", "Male"}))
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateofBirth, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateofBirth, new { @class = "form-control", @InputType = "date" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cuisine_1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine", new SelectList(new[] { "African", "American",
               "Asian", "Bakery", "British", "Carribean", "Chinese", "Continetal", "Eastern European", 
               "French", "German", "Greek", "Indian", "Irish", "Italian", "Japanese", "Mediteranean", 
               "Mexican", "Middle Eastern", "Pizza", "Pub", "Steakhouse", "Sushi", "Thai", "Vegetarian", 
               "Vietnamese"  }))
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cuisine_2, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine", new SelectList(new[] { "African", "American", 
               "Asian", "Bakery", "British", "Carribean", "Chinese", "Continetal", "Eastern European", 
               "French", "German", "Greek", "Indian", "Irish", "Italian", "Japanese", "Mediteranean",
               "Mexican", "Middle Eastern", "Pizza", "Pub", "Steakhouse", "Sushi", "Thai", "Vegetarian", 
               "Vietnamese"  }))
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cuisine_3, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine", new SelectList(new[] { "African", "American", 
               "Asian", "Bakery", "British", "Carribean", "Chinese", "Continetal", "Eastern European", 
               "French", "German", "Greek", "Indian", "Irish", "Italian", "Japanese", "Mediteranean",
               "Mexican", "Middle Eastern", "Pizza", "Pub", "Steakhouse", "Sushi", "Thai", "Vegetarian", 
               "Vietnamese"  }))
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Register view model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cuisine")]
        public string Cuisine { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public string DateofBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cuisine 1")]
        public string Cuisine_1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cuisine 2")]
        public string Cuisine_2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cuisine 3")]
        public string Cuisine_3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Account controller register view

```
// POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, EmailID = model.EmailID, Gender = model.Gender, DateofBirth = model.DateofBirth,
                UserCuisineInfo = new UserCuisineInfo
                {
                    Cuisine_1 = model.Cuisine_1,
                    Cuisine_2 = model.Cuisine_2,
                    Cuisine_3 = model.Cuisine_3
                }
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
```

Application user model

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        // stores users details in the user table
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName {get; set;}
        public string EmailID {get; set;}
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string DateofBirth { get; set; }

        // stores users cuisine choice in a separate table
        public virtual UserCuisineInfo UserCuisineInfo { get; set; }


    }
```

UserCuisineInfo

```
public class UserCuisineInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Cuisine_1 { get; set; }
        public string Cuisine_2 { get; set; }
        public string Cuisine_3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave all your dropdowns a name of Cuisine.  You need to change them to Cuisine_1, Cuisine_2 and Cuisine_3.

Answer (score 1):

You have three identically named dropdowns called `Cuisine`. Update them so they reflect the properties on your model:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine_1", ...

 @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine_2", ...

 @Html.DropDownList("Cuisine_3", ...
```

When these controls are rendered, they will produce a form control like:

```
<select name="Cuisine_1" ....
```

The `name` attribute's value is used in model binding, and must correspond to the name of the property in your ViewModel.